What is the proper way to remove a brokers from a kraft cluster?
before couple month's we installed in production environment 34 Kafka Kraft machines with version - apache 3.5 , all machines are working well in the cluster , when topics are created with replica 3 per topic
after re-sizing again the cluster spec and consider that messages per second from producers side are much less then we thought , then we decided to remove 5-6 Kafka Kraft machines from the cluster
what are the steps to remove/exclude/decommissioned completely the machines from the cluster ?
